# Identifying column indices that a subsetted np array came from in larger np array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have a "large" numpy array like follows:

```
from numpy import array
large = array([[-0.047391  , -0.10926778, -0.00899118,  0.07461428, -0.07667476,
         0.06961918,  0.09440736,  0.01648382, -0.04102225, -0.05038805,
        -0.00930337,  0.3667651 , -0.02803499,  0.02597451, -0.1218804 ,
         0.00561949],
       [-0.00253788, -0.08670117, -0.00466262,  0.07330351, -0.06403728,
         0.00301005,  0.12807456,  0.01198117, -0.04290793, -0.06138136,
        -0.01369276,  0.37094407, -0.03747804,  0.04444246, -0.01162705,
         0.00554793]])
```

And a "small" array that was subsetted from `large`.

```
small = array([[-0.10926778, -0.07667476,  0.09440736],
       [-0.08670117, -0.06403728,  0.12807456]])
```

Without any other information, how could we identify the column indices in `large` from which the `small` array was generated?

In this case, the answer is 1, 4, 6 (starting at 0 as done in python).

What would be a generalizable way to determine this?

Comment: `np.where(np.isin(...))`. See the related questions on [\[numpy\] isin](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnumpy%5D+isin), this is probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (not sure how you want to squeeze the result from 2D down to 1D?):

```
>>> np.isin(large,small)
array([[False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

>>> np.where(np.isin(large,small)) # tuple of arrays
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]), array([1, 4, 6, 1, 4, 6]))

# And generalizing, if you really want that as 2x2x3 array of indices:
idxs = array(np.where(np.isin(large,small)))
idxs.reshape( (2,) + small.shape )

array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 4, 6],
        [1, 4, 6]]])
```